# Calculate variations of eigenvectors w.r.t input matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

From the eigen decomposition :

$$A = PDP^T$$
I would like to calculate $dP$ w.r.t $dA$.

I start like this :

$$dA = dPDP^T + PdDP^T + PDdP^T$$

Since we only consider variations in eigenvectors and not eigenvalues, $dD = O$.

So :

$$dA = dPDP^T + PDdP^T$$

Now I know that $d(P^T) = (dP)^T$, but then I would be stuck with some $dP$ and $dP^T$, for which it would be difficult to isolate $dP$.

I noticed than $P^{-1} = P^T$ by definition of the eigen decomposition.
So I can write : 
$$dP^T = d(P^{-1}) = -P^{-1}dPP^{-1} = -P^TdPP^T$$

I get :

$$dA = dPDP^T + PDdP^T$$
$$dA = dPDP^T + PD(-P^TdPP^T)$$
$$dA = dPDP^T - PDP^TdPP^T$$
$$dA = dPDP^T - AdPP^T$$

And I'm stuck here, I can't manage to factorize the right part with a single $dP$ in order to get something of the form :
$$dP = f(dA)$$
Any ideas on how to do this ? I feel like I need a second equation...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By vectorizing the last equation, you can obtain something in the desired form
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dA) &= {\rm vec}(dP\,DP^T - A\,dP\,P^T) \cr
da &= (PD\otimes I - P\otimes A)\,dp \cr
dp &= (PD\otimes I - P\otimes A)^{-1}\,da \cr
\frac{\partial p}{\partial a} &= (PD\otimes I - P\otimes A)^{-1} \cr
}$$
where $\otimes$ represents the Kronecker product.

Rather than vectorization, you could use fourth-order tensors instead.
$$\eqalign{
dA &= ({\mathcal E}PD-A{\mathcal E}P):dP
}$$ where ${\mathcal E}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial P}$ is a 4th order tensor whose components can be written in terms of delta symbols as
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal E}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} \cr
{\mathcal B} &= A{\mathcal E}P \implies
{\mathcal B}_{ikln} = \sum_j\sum_m A_{ij}{\mathcal E}_{jklm}P_{mn} 
= A_{il}P_{kn}\cr
}$$
and the colon represents a double-dot product, i.e.
$$M={\mathcal B}:{dP} \implies M_{ij}=\sum_k\sum_l {\mathcal B}_{ijkl}\,dP_{kl}$$

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the Kronecker product... So you vectorize the matrices in order to be able to write their jacobian as a matrix, instead of a 4D tensor, if I understand correctly ? Do you have a ref for the elementary operations and identities that allow you to switch between vec() and $\otimes$ ? How you get from the first equation to the second is unclear to me...
Is this the only way to get $dP$ w.r.t $dA$, or is there another way without vectorizing ?

Comment: Check out the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) page at Wikipedia. If you want to avoid vectorization, then you must deal with 4th order tensors.

Comment: okay, thank you very much for this, and for taking the time to detail the method with fourth-order tensors!